# TeamCity не может подключиться к базе данных во время установки

Tags: sql-server, teamcity, setup

Здравствуйте, устанавливаю TeamCity. мне нужно что бы он сохранял свои логи в MS SQL Server (я использую 2016 development). Я скачал и закинул в папку lib > jdbc файл sqljdbc42, введя данные аутентификации (мне нужна sql auth, но можно и обычная windows auth), после нажатия на кнопку Proceed, TC пытается создать базу данных, делает это где-то 3-5 минут и потом выдает ошибку, что не может подключиться к моему серверу (он локальный), также я пытался подключиться к БД на удаленном сервере, но получаю тот же результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> The TCP/IP connection to the host DESKTOP-UPIKOD7, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.". (after 10 attempt(s); total time spent waiting 146341.758 ms; driver version 4.2.6420.100; java.version=1.8.0_66; jdk.tls.client.protocols=[]; jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=[MD2, RSA keySize < 1024]; jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=[SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 768])
>
> SQL exception: The TCP/IP connection to the host DESKTOP-UPIKOD7, port
> 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the
> connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is
> running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make
> sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
> (after 10 attempt(s); total time spent waiting 146341.758 ms; driver
> version 4.2.6420.100; java.version=1.8.0_66;
> jdk.tls.client.protocols=[]; jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=[MD2, RSA
> keySize < 1024]; jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=[SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize <
> 768])

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте снова. решение проблемы скрывалось в отключенном TCP сервисе, подробнее о решении этой проблемы вы можете прочитать https://blog.jayway.com/2014/08/08/installing-configuring-teamcity-on-windows-with-ms-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Я когда ставил тоже об это бился, как и многие другие. У меня даже в файле с комментариями шагов установки много мата осталось по этому поводу. Проще оказалось выбрать внутреннюю БД, потом можно будет перейти на MS SQL. Третьим этапом можно будет на виндовую авторизацию перейти, если под AD сидите.

upd:
Кстати, помню со строкой подключения тоже скачки были. Вот пример как она должна выглядеть:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName\\sqlInstance:1433;databaseName=TeamCity;integratedSecurity=true
```

Файл конфига находится: `..\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\database.properties`

Если порыться и есть время в наличии, то можно попробовать чисто за счет строки из твоей ситуации выйти. Честно не помню почему не получалось тогда, может в новых версиях меньше проблем.

Comment: спасибо, попробую. Надеюсь что-нибудь получится